# The following code is supposed to return true if i compare a1 with a2. But it is returning false

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

class Array {
private:
    int* array;
    int s;
public:
    Array()
        {
            array = NULL;
            s = 0;
                    
        }
    Array(int size)
        {
            size = (size > 0 ? size : 10);
            array = new int[size]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                array[i] = 0;
                    
        }
    Array(int* arr, int size)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                *(arr + i) = *(array + i);
            
            }
        }
    Array(const Array& a):s(a.s)
        {
            array = new int[s];
            for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
                array[i] = a.array[i];
                    
        }
    int& operator[](int i)
        {
            return array[i];
        }
    const Array& operator=(const Array& obj)
        {
            if (&obj != this) { 
                if (s != obj.s) {
                    delete[] array; 
                    s = obj.s;
                    array = new int[s]; 
                }
            
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
                array[i] = obj.array[i];
            return *this;
        }
    bool operator==(const Array&obj)const
        {
            if (s != obj.s)
                return false;
            for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
                if (array[i] != obj.array[i])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
                
    ~Array() {
        delete[] array;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Array a1(5);
    int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    Array a2(arr, 5);
    a1 = a2;
}
```

I am trying to run above program which is supposed to return true if I compare a1 and a2.but when I run this program I am getting false. Kindly check the overloaded operators
and let me know where is the mistake. I have overloaded both assignment and equal operators but still I am not getting the actual output.

Comment: Where are you comparing them? `a1 = a2;` is an assignment, not comparison.

Comment: I am comparing it on the google test cases i.e ASSERT_EQ(true, a1 == a2);

Comment: I strongly question what your intention was for this: `*(arr + i) = *(array + i);` in that alternative constructor.  `array` is indeterminate, and more important, `arr` is supposed to be the *source* of the incoming data, isn't it? It seems you forgot to (a) allocate space for `array`, and (b) retain `size` in the member `s`.

Comment: I was simply trying to assign values of original array to the parameters of constructor.

Comment: `*(arr + i) = *(array + i);` -- This is simply: `arr[i] = array[i];`.  That looks a lot simpler, and reveals what the issue is.

Comment: Yeah i know both are same but where is the actual mistake which results in failing the test case?

Comment: @XcroodCoding That's completely *backward* from what that code should be doing, and it is invoking *undefined behavior* while doing it. Just look at the constructor and ask yourself where should data be copied *from* and *to* in that context. once you see that, you'll also see there is no memory at `array`. In fact, no members (`array` or `s`) are being properly setup in that ctor, *and* you're copying in the wrong direction to make matters worse.

Comment: @XcroodCoding You do realize that the entity on the left-hand side of the `=` is what is being assigned to?

Comment: The "actual mistake" is that the `Array(int* arr, int size)` constructor never does `array = new int[size];`. So everything after this causes undefined behavior.

Comment: OH! My bad. I have changed it from left to right but still it is returning false?

Comment: Instead of being tripped up by a faulty `operator=` with the code you have now, you could simply do this: `Array& operator=(const Array& obj) { Array temp(obj); std::swap(temp.s, s); std::swap(temp.array, array); return *this; }`

Comment: Also ` if (s != obj.s)` in `operator==` is comparing the addresses of the array which will always be different unless you actually compare the same objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three issues. The first is that you never allocated memory in the `Array(int*, int)` constructor for the array. The second is that this assignment...

```
*(arr + i) = *(array + i);
```

should be

```
*(array + i) = *(arr + i);
```

or even better

```
array[i] = arr[i];
```

The third is that you are neglecting to assign `s` to the length of the array in some of your constructors.

Comment: Thank you for answer it works after the changes proposed by you!